# App broken after upgrading to Oreo

Tags: android-8.0-oreo

I have an app that has two Fragments in a ViewPager.  One Fragment has a ListView and the other has a ExpandableListView.  Prior to my upgrade to Oreo, this app worked just fine, i.e., OnItemClicked would be executed when an item in the list is clicked.  Since the upgrade to Oreo, neither the ListView nor the ExpandableListView respond to clicks on the list.  I do have ListView in other parts of the app and that works, but the two in the ViewPager do not.

Is there a change in Oreo that I need to know about to fix this?

Comment: Please show the code you're trying in an [edit].

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.  I'm not sure what changed in Oreo, but something in my Listview layouts was becoming focusable with the change to Oreo.  For each item layout I use in Listview or ExpandableListView, I added the following parameter to the top element of the layout hierarchy:

android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"

This fixed the problem!